# Bokeh bold some text in title

Tags: python, latex, bokeh

Good day,

I am quite new to Bokeh and I'm making a few charts. I want to bold only part of the text in the title of the chart.

---

As an example, I want to take this:

- "Number of schools in District B in 2022"

And turn it into this:

- "Number of **schools** in District B in **2022**"

---

Is there a way to do that with a Bokeh chart and maybe some LaTeX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic plot titles are rendered directly on the HTML canvas, which has very simple text rendering options. Bokeh only exposes one set of text properties for standard titles. Accordingly, what you are asking for is not possible using standard titles.

For now, your best option is to not use a plot title at all. Instead. Put a `Div` above the plot in a column, and use the `Div` for a "fancy title" (since can contain arbitrary HTML to look however you like).

In the near future (Bokeh 3.0) LaTeX for plot titles will also be an option.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks @bigreddot! I will definitely do that